# Try to import one cell from XLS table with alasql

Tags: javascript, sql, alasql

Ok I got it but now i cant use variable(nomer) into WHERE.
Variable set in function and its just number

my code:

```
var nomer
element.addEventListener( 'click', function (textbase, input ) { 
 nomer = element.id;
      setPrice(nomer); 
    
      function setPrice(nomer){ 
      var printResult = function(result){ console.log(result)}; 
      alasql('SELECT te FROM XLSX("../MDF_PANELS.XLS") WHERE f = nomer',[], 
      function (data) {printResult(data); }) }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

You can create SQL query as usual JavaScript string.
Need right comment your variale and in alasql use " instead '

```
function setPrice(nomer){
                    console.log(nomer)
                    var printResult = function(result){ console.log(result)};
                    
 alasql("SELECT te  FROM XLSX('../MDF_PANELS.XLS') WHERE f = "+nomer+"",[],
        function (data) {printResult(data); })
                        
}
```